# Why and When should I "Extract Composite" instead of "Extract Superclass"

Tags: design-patterns, composite

I'm reading a book called [Refactoring to Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321213351), and in this book there is a section titled: Extract Composite (page 214).

What it suggests is that if a bunch of subclasses have common functionality you should extract that functionality to a new superclass. This sounds pretty straight forward.

What is the difference between `Extract Composite` and `Extract Superclass`?

Well, according to the reading and the diagrams... the composite should be a **new** superclass to your child classes. See the following diagram:

[image]

**Question**:
What is the purpose of creating a new "CompositeTag" superclass? Why wouldn't you want to just move the code-duplication to its original base class (Node)?

Comment: There seems to be no difference between extract super class and extract composite, except how high up the hierarchy you take the common-code. This is what was just explained to me... if anybody else wants to add their 2 cents feel free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wish I had my copy handy, but I would say thet "Extract Composite" is a special case of "Extract Superclass"  A [composite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) is a specific type of inheritance relationship, and I guess the author felt it needed to be called out separately.  The diagram does indeed illustrate the kind of operations often done with composites.  I think in the example given, not all subclasses are composites though, so that functionality cannot be pulled into the base class.  Still, it does feel a bit like the author was just padding the book a bit :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an analogy in terms of `Visual` and `UIElement` from WPF. Let's pretend we're developing some controls, and we discover that (for whatever strange reason) we don't have mouse events, and that buttons kind of need them.

We could put mouse events in `Visual`, or we could put them in `UIElement`. Since it doesn't make sense to have mouse events on something that's not part of a GUI, it logically belongs in `UIElement`, and that's where we put them.

**Answer**: Semantics, and especially the Single Responsibility Principle. `Visual` should take care of things like effects and transforms, while `UIElement` should take care of focus and input etc.

I'd try to offer a more pertinent example, but I don't have a concrete set of classes to work with. If you can logically separate functionality into self-contained sub-classes, by all means do so.